# Scrapy, how to extract h3 content?

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to extract the web content in every `div class="summary"`.
And in every `summary` div, I want to extract the data in every class in the div.

The following are my snippet.

```
questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="summary"]')
for question in questions:
    item = StackItem()
    # get the hyperlink of h3 text
    item['title'] = question.xpath('a[@h3]/text()').extract()[0]
    yield item
```

How should I write the xpath contenct in my code?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What output do you get if you remove your [0]?

Comment: @Error404E, empty list `[]`. So there is something wrong with the xpath parameters

Comment: I never had used Scrapy but what if you put your first xpath like this: `//div[@class="summary"]/h3`?

Comment: @Error404, I have tried that, I works fine, But I need more data.

Comment: Then, as suggested on an answer by @har07 you have to read your h3 before your `a`, as `a` is a child of `h3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd XPath looks for *`a` element that is direct child of `div[@class="summary"]` and has attribute `h3`*, which doesn't exist in the HTML posted.

The correct XPath to get `a` element within `h3` from the `div` would be as follow :

```
h3/a/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to put it may be:

```
questions = Selector(response).xpath('div[@class="summary"]/h3')
```

and in order to grab the data from the `<a>`:

```
item['title'] = question.xpath('/a/text()').extract()[0]
```

This is useful if all the data you want to extract is inside of the `h3` tag.